# How to Enable TLS 1.2 on MS SQL Server 2012 SP1?

Tags: sql-server-2012, jdbc

im having trouble connecting to **MS SQL Server 2012 SP1** with regards to TLS Handshake. as stated by microsoft, SP1 only supports TLSv1 to TLSv1.1, if i'm not mistaken. I have been developing a spring/java application which uses **JPA/jdbc** to connect to the database but it requires me to use TLSv1.2 minimum. is there a way to enable **TLSv1.2** on SQL Server 2012 SP1? or applying the SP2 packages to get the support for **TLS 1.2** will not affect or has backward compatibility with old version of connectors.